# Javascript append some calculation results into table rows one by one

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm working on a simple electron / node.js app, which takes input information locally, do some calculation and present calculation results in a table

Input:

```
10s of rows of features info
ID | length | depth |
```

Calculation: takes about seconds for each feature calculation.

Output:

```
Some amount of row from input, but with a results column 
ID | length | depth | Results
```

I tried to append the results to tables for presenting, the code looks like this

```
<table id = 'results-table'>
    <th>ID</th><th>length</th><th>depth</th><th>Results</th>
</table>
```

```
function getCrackTableValues(){
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
  var table = document.getElementById('input-table'); //get info from input table
  for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) { //skip table head tart from second row
      const crackID = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML; //input
      var a_m = Number(table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML); // input
      var c_m = Number(table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML); //input
      var result = foo(a_m, c_m); //foo just for example, takes seconds for calculation 
      var newRow = document.getElementById('results-table').insertRow(); //output table
      newRow.innerHTML = '<td>'+ crackID+ 
                        '</td><td>' + `${a_m.toFixed(1)}` +
                        '</td><td>' + `${c_m.toFixed(1)}` +
                        '</td><td>' + `${result.toFixed(1)}` + //append results to output table
                        '</td>';
  }
  document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}
```

The code works ok, but with couple issues.

**Q1**: I was hoping once a single calculation is done, it will show results on the output table, and move to next entry's calculation. So the user could see current results, while the calculation of the rest rows are going on.

Currently it seems the output table won't show up until all the calculations are done.

Are there any ways I could use to make the results table **grows/shows up one by one, as calculation of each row goes on**?

**Q2**: I was trying to disable the cursor while the calculation goes on `document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';`. and enable the cursor back on after all calculations are done.

But it seems this line executed **after** calculation, it would just disabled the cursor and flash back on.

Are there any potential issue with my current implementation? My node.js is v12.16.3, on a old 32bit windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of both issues is the same: the UI won't get chance to update until it manages to escape your very-long-running loop.

You need to change `foo()` to become an async function. You've not shown any details, so I will assume it is pure CPU calculation and has no file or network access points.

I think I'd first pull out the loop contents into another function. And then I've put the loop termination condition at the top of that new function:

```
function processOneRow(r){
  const table = document.getElementById('input-table');
  if(r >= table.rows.length){ //All done
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    return;
    }

  const crackID = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML;
  const a_m = Number(table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML);
  const c_m = Number(table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML);

  const result = foo(a_m, c_m);

  const newRow = document.getElementById('results-table').insertRow();
  newRow.innerHTML = '<td>'+ ...;

  setTimeout(processOneRow, 0, r+1)
}
```

And then you can start it going by calling it for the first row:

```
function getCrackTableValues(){
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
  setTimeout(processOneRow, 0, 1)
}
```

The use of `setTimeout()` with a 0ms delay, gives the UI thread time to update each time, before it will call `processOneRow()` on the next row of the input table.

Aside: Putting the code to restore the cursor inside `processOneRow()` is a bit of a code smell. If this code was going in a library, I would probably use `before()`/`after()` hooks. (You could then also make sure the `after()` hook gets called if there is an exception thrown.)

The other way to approach this would be to use [worker threads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) and move the `foo(a_m, c_m)` calculation there. That would then naturally be async. Beyond the extra complexity, the downside of that is if `foo()` uses data, it needs to be kept with it in that worker thread, which gets complex if the same data is needed in the main thread. But, otherwise, it is a better solution for long running processes.

Comment: thanks Darren. Just wondering if its always the case that UI could only be updated after other running loops are done? even if the ui command appears before other command in the script.

Comment: Yes, always the case, see "Run to completion" section at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop   (searching for articles on JavaScript event loop is good background reading.)